# Linq to Entities error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, mvvm, linq-to-entities

In MVVM, i am getting an entity set from the repository to viewmodel. While trying to access the elements of the entity, it throws an exception:

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'InsurableRisk.Entities.QueriesParameter ElementAt[QueriesParameter](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[InsurableRisk.Entities.QueriesParameter], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Here is my code:

Repository:

```
public IQueryable<QueriesParameter> GetParams(int QKey)
    {
        IQueryable<QueriesParameter> param = (from Q in Context.QueriesParameters
                                              where (Q.QueryKey == QKey)
                                              select Q);
        return param;
    }
```

Service:

```
public IQueryable<QueriesParameter> GetParams(int QKey)
    {
        return _repository.GetParams(QKey);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
    paramLabel = new string[] { "ParamLabel1", "ParamLabel2", "ParamLabel3", "ParamLabel4", "ParamLabel5", "ParamLabel6" };
    param = new string[] { "Param1", "Param2", "Param3", "Param4", "Param5", "Param6" };
    paramVisibility = new string[] { "ParamVisiblity1", "ParamVisiblity2", "ParamVisiblity3", "ParamVisiblity4", "ParamVisiblity5", "ParamVisiblity6" };
    paramLabelVisibility = new string[] { "ParamLabelVisiblity1", "ParamLabelVisiblity2", "ParamLabelVisiblity3", "ParamLabelVisiblity4", "ParamLabelVisiblity5", "ParamLabelVisiblity6" };

    private Dictionary<int, string> m_queryNames;
    private Dictionary<int, string> m_ReadOnlyQueryNames;
    private int m_SelectedQueryNames;

    public int SelectedQueryNames
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SelectedQueryNames;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_SelectedQueryNames != value)
            {
                m_SelectedQueryNames = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedQueryNames");
                var QKey = m_SelectedQueryNames;
                var sqlQuery = _service.GetQuery(QKey);
                var paramCount = _service.GetParamCount(QKey);
                //code to make the run button visible and the parameters to be visible  
                m_Visibility = true;
                IQueryable<QueriesParameter> param = _service.GetParams(QKey);
                for (int i = 1; i <= paramCount; i++)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged(paramLabelVisibility[i]);
                    OnPropertyChanged(paramVisibility[i]);
                    QueriesParameter qParam = param.ElementAt(i);  <!-- I get the exception here -->
                    m_LabelName = qParam.ParameterName;
                    OnPropertyChanged(paramLabel[i]);
                    //OnPropertyChanged(param[i]);                        
                }                    
            }
        }
```

Any help as in why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `ElementAt` is not supported by LINQ to Entities (indeed, how you will translate it into SQL?). Here is list of [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx).

You can enumerate over params instead:

```
IQueryable<QueriesParameter> param = _service.GetParams(QKey);
int i = 1; // btw why you are iterating from index 1? It should be zero!
foreach(var p in param)
{
   OnPropertyChanged(paramLabelVisibility[i]);
   OnPropertyChanged(paramVisibility[i]);
   QueriesParameter qParam = p; // here
   m_LabelName = qParam.ParameterName;
   OnPropertyChanged(paramLabel[i]);
   i++;
}
```

Another option - move query to client side by calling `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()`. Then Linq to Objects will be used, where you can use `ElementAt(index)` method or via indexer `[index]`:

```
 List<QueriesParameter> param = _service.GetParams(QKey).ToList(); 
 //... your code
 QueriesParameter qParam = param[i];
```